# How to kill LightDM?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, jessie-lite

So I installed LightDM on Raspbian lite, but I forgot to install a desktop manager. Now, I can't get out of the LightDM login screen! Ctrl-Alt-F1 through to F6 doesn't work! Neither does cancel or login get me out either. Also it looks like the Raspberry Pi doesn't have a BIOS screen either.

How do I get back to the terminal?

Comment: Have you tried SSH?

Comment: The `CTRL-ALT-<Fn>` keys ought to work (they do on my system). An alternative is to stick the SD card into another computer and fix things up (probably just need to remove a symlink from `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` if you're on Raspbian Jessie).

Answer (score 3):

Get to a terminal (SSH or local) then run `sudo stop lightdm` or `sudo service lightdm stop`.